# Inject a property into a Class level annotation in Spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-3

My requirement is to Inject a property into a Class level annotation.

What I want is something like the following but @Value only support Injection of fields or methods:

```
@MyAnno(someproperty = @Value("${someproperty}"))
public class My {
...
}
```

Comment: You cannot do it. What's your specific problem?

Comment: Ya figured as much. What I want is to make the annotation value configurable via a property file.

Comment: There is no way to do it. If you talk about specific annotation, there can be alternative configuration approaches.